# Find and replace with MySQL version 5.5.3

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find a weird character thats in front of my £ sign and replace it with nothing.

Coding I tried was

```
update [orders_total] 
set [text]=replace([text],'[Â]','[]');
```

but mysql returns this

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near '[orders_total] set [text]=replace([text],'[Ã‚]','[]')' at line 1

I know nothing of Mysql but its going to take me ages to manually remove these chars so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use back ticks instead of squared brackets. Back tick, on many keyboards, is shift + ~ (tilde)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats not mysql syntax and in mysql it should be as

```
update orders_total 
set text=replace(text,'Â','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Abhik is absolutely right in his answer. An alternate form of writing MySQL queries is:

```
update `orders_total` set `text` = replace(`text`, '..', '...');
```

Backticks are not required. They may be valuable when a table's column is named `order`, for example. `Order` is a reserved keyword used in `order by ...` clause. In order to use a reserved keyword like `order`, use backticks.

Example:

```
select `order`, `id`, ... from `tablename` where .... order by `order`;
```